# converting string to decimal not working in ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, decimal

I've a varchar column with sample values as:

```
amount
        -- null value
1067.00
234.10
337.28
357.00
400.00
489.40
500.00
8000.00
```

I tried to convert this field to decimal and get the sum but I can not.

```
SUM(cast(isnull(t.amount,0) as decimal(12,2))) AS TotalAmount
```

also 
`isnull(t.amount,'0') as amount` is not working. How to convert the varchar column to decimal and get the sum.

Comment: Why is it varchar in the first place? You have decimal or float types.

Comment: `is not working`, what does this mean? are you getting errors?

Comment: when I do `isnull(t.amount,'0') as amount` NULL is not replaced by 0

Comment: Your NULL value looks like an empty string ('') which is not the same as NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to handle NULL and/or an empty string. Here's one using [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177562.aspx);

```
SUM(cast(isnull(nullif(t.amount, ''),0) as decimal(12,2))) AS TotalAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Before [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187928.aspx) you could check your value with [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186272.aspx) function like this:

Try this:

```
create table #tmp ([Amount] varchar(50));

insert into #tmp values (NULL);
insert into #tmp values ('123.3');
insert into #tmp values ('');
insert into #tmp values (' ');
insert into #tmp values ('hello?');
insert into #tmp values ('53.23');
insert into #tmp values ('7.0');
insert into #tmp values ('3.423');

select sum(case when ISNUMERIC([Amount]) = 1 then convert(float, [Amount]) else 0 end)
  from #tmp
```

Output:

```
186,953
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create a `CTE` with converted values and call the sum subsequently.

```
with ConvertedTable as
(
    select cast(isnull(Amount,0) as decimal(12,2)) as [NumAmount]
    from TestTable
)
select sum([NumAmount]) as [SumOfConvertedTable] from ConvertedTable
```

Output:

```
SumOfConvertedTable
-------------------
11384.78
```

Comment: how would this make any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work in sqlserver 2012:

```
SUM(try_convert(decimal(12,2), t.amount)) AS TotalAmount
```